# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync dialog does not show on screen (.ms-Dialog-main css issue?)

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

On chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on OSX when I call Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync with displayInIframe set to true in the Outlook Web App the .ms-Dialog-main div does not appear on the screen. The whole screen simply gets taken over by .ms-Overlay ms-Overlay--dark.

See attached screenshot: [dialog content invisible on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofPSL.jpg)

This also occurs on chrome incognito (ruling out conflict with chrome extensions) and firefox as well, oddly it does not occur in safari.

Playing around with styles in the chrome inspector (ie. setting position absolute to .ms-Dialog-main at least gets the dialog content to appear on the screen, albeit not centered see screenshot: [dialog content after tweaking styles in web inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBi26.jpg)

Tweaking the width, or the height in the options parameter for Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync does not seem to help at all.

Would a Microsoft engineer be able to help resolve this?

Comment: did you find anything related to this issue? I am facing same issue with word office365.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code? We've been trying to repro this and couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I failed to repro displayDialogAsync issue with the same chrome version on OSX. Is it possible to share more details, like mainifest or some prototype code, which might be helpful for repro.